# How to typeset dimensional tolerances (mechanical engineering) with LaTeX?

Tags: formatting, units, technical-drawing

Is there a package which allows to typeset dimensional tolerances as used in mechanical engineering like:
[image: Example for engineering dimensional tolerances]?

I have to use them in the text and wonder how to do that best. So I'm searching for a package which can

- correctly typeset the upper and lower limits
  (also in combination with length units! I admit that I'm not sure how to do that the best way.)
- also makes available the symbols for form tolerances like roundness, cylindricity, straightness, etc.

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a math symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: Tolerances have been drawn here: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53478/32245]

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Thank you very much for the link!

Answer (score 5):

You should use the `siunitx` package to format all your numbers and units.
The symbol can be drawn using `\diameter` from the `wasysym` package and the tolerances are simple math super- and subscripts:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\newcommand{\tol}[3]{\ensuremath{\si{#1}^{+\num{#2}}_{-\num{#3}}}}

\newcommand{\diatol}[3]{\ensuremath{\diameter\si{#1}^{+\num{#2}}_{-\num{#3}}}}

\begin{document}

\diatol{0,125}{0.000}{0.001}

\tol{2,225\meter}{0.100}{0.20}

\tol{2,225m}{0.100}{0.20}

\end{document}
```

#### Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: I think the tolerances need to be in scriptscriptsize.

Comment: This is a mixed bag question of normal as well as [Geometric tolerances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_dimensioning_and_tolerancing) . I think it is more a job for TikZ

Comment: In technical drawings, the tolerances are set on size smaller than the target measure. From that point of view, scriptsize is ok.