# How to create geometry tolerance symbols with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing, engineering

I am a beginner in LaTeX, trying to use it for an industrial metrology test report, where I need to use geometry tolerances. I have tentatively made a first one with TikZ, but this is hard coded and therefore not flexible. I need in some cases to change the number of reference planes from only 1 to 3 such as in the example (A,B,C) Conversely there is a need to use one or two digits in the main tolerance, and sometimes a symbol (such as "DIA") as prefix. It seemed to me that using chains would be a much more promising route, but I cannot make it work, the symbol is not placed at the left side, and the lines do not align properly. Would someone suggest a solution?

```
\documentclass[11pt ]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\Large
\newcommand{\postol}[4]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
\draw (-1em,0) -- (1em,0);
\draw(0,-1em) -- (0,1em);
\draw (0,0) circle ( .6 em);
\draw (1em, -1em) --(1em, 1em);
\draw (2.5em, 0) node{#1};
\draw(4em,-1em) -- (4em,1em);
\draw (5em, 0) node{#2};
\draw(6em,-1em) -- (6em,1em);
\draw (7em, 0) node{#3};
\draw(8em,-1em) -- (8em,1em);
\draw (9em, 0) node{#4};
\draw (-1 em,-1em) rectangle (10 em, 1 em);
\end{tikzpicture}} %

\postol{0.32}{A}{B}{C}

\newcommand{\tolgeom}[1]{
\node[rectangle, draw, on chain=going right]{
#1}}%

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,
    start chain,
    node distance=0pt]
    \draw (-1em,0) -- (1em,0);
\draw(0,-1em) -- (0,1em);
\draw (0,0) circle ( .6 em);
\tolgeom{0.32};\tolgeom{A}; \tolgeom{B};\tolgeom{C};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've defined node shapes for all the symbols found on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_dimensioning_and_tolerancing#Symbols, plus one symbol for creating modifiers that takes a letter as its argument.

The line `\tol{type=position,3,2,1,modifier=M}` will print

[image]

The symbols are accessed using `type=<type>`. Here's a list of all the types that are available:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{tolposition}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \foreach \anchor in {center,north,south,west,east,north east,south east,north west, south west}{
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{\anchor}
  }
  \backgroundpath{%
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y

    %% The path
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners
        {\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}
        {\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpointscale{-1}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@xb}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-\pgf@yb}}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{0.6\pgf@yb}
 }
}

\pgfdeclareshape{tolstraightness}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \foreach \anchor in {center,north,south,west,east,north east,south east,north west, south west}{
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{\anchor}
  }
  \backgroundpath{%
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y

    %% The path
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners
        {\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}
        {\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpointscale{-1}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{-0.6\pgf@xb}{0pt}}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.6\pgf@xb}{0pt}}
 }
}

\pgfdeclareshape{tolflatness}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] 
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \foreach \anchor in {center,north,south,west,east,north east,south east,north west, south west}{
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{\anchor}
  }
  \backgroundpath{%
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y

    %% The path
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners
        {\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}
        {\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpointscale{-1}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.6\pgf@xb}{-0.3\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.3\pgf@xb}{-0.3\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.6\pgf@xb}{0.3\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-0.3\pgf@xb}{0.3\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathclose
 }
}


\pgfdeclareshape{tolcircularity}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] 
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \foreach \anchor in {center,north,south,west,east,north east,south east,north west, south west}{
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{\anchor}
  }
  \backgroundpath{%
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y

    %% The path
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners
        {\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}
        {\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpointscale{-1}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{0.6\pgf@yb}
 }
}

\pgfdeclareshape{tolcylindricity}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] 
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \foreach \anchor in {center,north,south,west,east,north east,south east,north west, south west}{
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{\anchor}
  }
  \backgroundpath{
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y

    %% The path
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners
        {\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}
        {\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpointscale{-1}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    {
        \pgftransformrotate{60}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@xb}{0.4\pgf@yb}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.6\pgf@xb}{0.4\pgf@yb}}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.6\pgf@xb}{-0.4\pgf@yb}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{-0.4\pgf@yb}}
    }
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{0.4\pgf@yb}
 }
}

\pgfdeclareshape{tolprofile line}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] 
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \foreach \anchor in {center,north,south,west,east,north east,south east,north west, south west}{
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{\anchor}
  }
  \backgroundpath{%
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y

    %% The path
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners
        {\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}
        {\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpointscale{-1}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.6\pgf@yb}{-0.3\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpatharc{180}{0}{0.6\pgf@yb}
 }
}

\pgfdeclareshape{tolprofile surface}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] 
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \foreach \anchor in {center,north,south,west,east,north east,south east,north west, south west}{
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{\anchor}
  }

  %% The path
  \backgroundpath{
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners
        {\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}
        {\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpointscale{-1}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.6\pgf@yb}{-0.3\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpatharc{180}{0}{0.6\pgf@yb}
    \pgfpathclose
 }
}


\pgfdeclareshape{tolperpendicularity}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] 
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \foreach \anchor in {center,north,south,west,east,north east,south east,north west, south west}{
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{\anchor}
  }

  %% The path
  \backgroundpath{
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners
        {\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}
        {\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpointscale{-1}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.6\pgf@yb}{-0.6\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.6\pgf@yb}{-0.6\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-0.6\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0.6\pgf@yb}}
 }
}

\pgfdeclareshape{tolangularity}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] 
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \foreach \anchor in {center,north,south,west,east,north east,south east,north west, south west}{
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{\anchor}
  }

  %% The path
  \backgroundpath{
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners
        {\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}
        {\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpointscale{-1}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.6\pgf@yb}{0.6\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-0.6\pgf@yb}{-0.6\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.6\pgf@yb}{-0.6\pgf@yb}}
 }
}


\pgfdeclareshape{tolparallelism}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] 
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \foreach \anchor in {center,north,south,west,east,north east,south east,north west, south west}{
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{\anchor}
  }

  %% The path
  \backgroundpath{
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners
        {\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}
        {\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpointscale{-1}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.5\pgf@yb}{-0.6\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0.6\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-0.6\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.5\pgf@yb}{0.6\pgf@yb}}
 }
}


\pgfdeclareshape{tolsymmetry}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] 
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \foreach \anchor in {center,north,south,west,east,north east,south east,north west, south west}{
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{\anchor}
  }

  %% The path
  \backgroundpath{
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners
        {\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}
        {\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpointscale{-1}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.4\pgf@yb}{-0.4\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.4\pgf@yb}{-0.4\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.6\pgf@yb}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.6\pgf@yb}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.4\pgf@yb}{0.4\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.4\pgf@yb}{0.4\pgf@yb}}
 }
}

\pgfdeclareshape{tolconcentricity}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] 
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \foreach \anchor in {center,north,south,west,east,north east,south east,north west, south west}{
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{\anchor}
  }

  %% The path
  \backgroundpath{
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners
        {\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}
        {\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpointscale{-1}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    {\pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{0.6\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{0.4\pgf@yb}
 }
}

\pgfdeclareshape{tolcircular runout}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] 
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \foreach \anchor in {center,north,south,west,east,north east,south east,north west, south west}{
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{\anchor}
  }

  %% The path
  \backgroundpath{
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners
        {\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}
        {\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpointscale{-1}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd
        {\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
        {\pgfpointpolar{50}{0.2\pgf@yb}}
    }
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd
        {\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
        {\pgfpointpolar{50}{-0.7\pgf@yb}}
    }
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    {\pgftransformrotate{-40}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.2\pgf@yb}{0.2\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.2\pgf@yb}{0.2\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0.7\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepath{fill}
    }
 }
}

\pgfdeclareshape{toltotal runout}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] 
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \foreach \anchor in {center,north,south,west,east,north east,south east,north west, south west}{
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{\anchor}
  }

  %% The path
  \backgroundpath{
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners
        {\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}
        {\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpointscale{-1}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd
        {\pgfpoint{-0.3\pgf@yb}{0pt}}
        {\pgfpointpolar{50}{0.2\pgf@yb}}
    }
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd
        {\pgfpoint{-0.3\pgf@yb}{0pt}}
        {\pgfpointpolar{50}{-0.7\pgf@yb}}
    }
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd
        {\pgfpoint{0.3\pgf@yb}{0pt}}
        {\pgfpointpolar{50}{-0.7\pgf@yb}}
    }
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd
        {\pgfpoint{0.3\pgf@yb}{0pt}}
        {\pgfpointpolar{50}{0.2\pgf@yb}}
    }
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    {
    \pgftransformxshift{-0.3\pgf@yb}
    \pgftransformrotate{-40}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.2\pgf@yb}{0.2\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.2\pgf@yb}{0.2\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0.7\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepath{fill}
    }
    {
    \pgftransformxshift{0.3\pgf@yb}
    \pgftransformrotate{-40}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.2\pgf@yb}{0.2\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.2\pgf@yb}{0.2\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0.7\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepath{fill}
    }
 }
}

\pgfdeclareshape{tolmodifier}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] 
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \foreach \anchor in {center,north,south,west,east,north east,south east,north west, south west}{
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{\anchor}
  }
  \backgroundpath{% this is new
    % store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    % construct main path
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners
        {\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}
        {\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpointscale{-1}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointlineattime{0.5}{\southwest}{\northeast}}{0.55\pgf@yb}
 }
}

\makeatother



\tikzset{
    tolstyle/.style={
        draw,
        on chain=going right,
        inner ysep=0pt,
        minimum height=1.7em
    },
    type/.style={tol#1},
    modifier/.style={tolmodifier,font=#1}
}

\newcommand{\tol}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.3em,
        start chain,
        node distance=-\pgflinewidth
    ]
        \foreach \content in {#1} {
            \IfSubStr{\content}{type}{
                \edef\donode{%
                    \noexpand\node[
                        tolstyle,
                        minimum width=\noexpand\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height},
                        \content
                    ]{};
                }
                \donode
            }{
                \IfSubStr{\content}{modifier}{
                \edef\donode{\noexpand\node[tolstyle,tolmodifier,minimum width=\noexpand\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height},\content]{};}
                \donode
            }
                \node[tolstyle]{\content};
            }
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{4.2cm}
\foreach \type in {straightness, flatness, circularity, cylindricity, profile line, profile surface, perpendicularity, angularity, parallelism, symmetry, position, concentricity, circular runout, total runout}{
    \texttt{\type}:\hfill \tol{type=\type}\par
}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{1cm}

Example usage:

\verb|\tol{type=position,3,2,1,modifier=M}|

\tol{type=position,3,2,1,modifier=M}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.This is beautiful. Is there a way to combine the commands, ie something that would be  more like \tol{\target}{0.32}{A}{B}{C} ?

Comment: I found myself the solution: \newcommand{\tol}[5]{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
     start chain,
     node distance=-\pgflinewidth
 ]
 #1;\tolgeom{#2}; \tolgeom{#3}; \tolgeom{#4}; \tolgeom{#5};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 }%
 
 \tol{\target}{0,32}{A}{B}{C}

Comment: @Yves: Will you always need five segments in your diagrams?

Comment: No there are cases where there are only 3 ie only one reference plane, such as "A".  I am not sure there is an  easy way (except of course dedicating one command to every case..) to take care of this situation, since the number of arguments define the number of "cells"...

Comment: @Yves: I've turned the whole thing into a macro that takes a comma separated list of cells as an argument. If you need a cell to *contain* a comma, you'll have to enclose it in `{...}` (so for example `\tol{target,A,{B,C}}`).

Comment: Thanks. Since there is a full series of tolerances differing by the symbol of the first cell, I have edited your code to "hard-code" the symbol into a \tolpos macro, and I have made similar macros for other symbols. I feel this is a lot easier than handling all symbols in a single macro. I need now to incorporate an optional symbol (a M in a circle, meaning "at maximum material")  following the number defining the tolerance. What is the best way to do this? Should I write a tikz macro \mcircled and call it from the main \tol or \tolpos macro or is another way possible and preferable?

Comment: @Yves: I've created proper node shapes for the different symbols now, including one called `modifier=<letter>` that typesets a letter inside a circle.

Comment: This comprehensive set of tolerances is magnificent and would deserve some publicity. There was a similar question on this site a while ago that was not really answered. Just a minor thing. I need to switch between both european and US numbering format. For this task, siunix does a magnificent job, since changing only one line \sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}} switches formats. However if I use \tol{type=concentricity,\num{1.2},A,B}, the 1,2 resulting number gets raised in its cell... I wonder if there is an easy fix....

Comment: @Yves: I'll try and make a package out of it. You can fix the misalignment by adding `text depth=0pt` to the `tolstyle` style.

Comment: Fantastic.A formal package will serve many users... Another detail: I believe that there should be the possibility to put the modifier immediately after the number (in the same cell). I am at home and cannot check right now, but I am almost sure...Is there a way to reach you privately for another thing? Alternately I can be reached at yves_paris at aliceads.fr

Comment: Please read yves_paris at aliceadsl.fr

Comment: I have loaded the code above (stripped from the preample) into the premable of an existing document (article class, standard LaTeX fonts) and the typesetting of the characters inside the tolerance are not sf, but the same as the main document. I could not explin this, as the \tol macro explicitely shifts to sf fonts. Moreover any attempt to change this before calling the \tol macro such as \sf \tol{type=position,3,2,1,modifier=M} fails also to make the change.  Any idea?

Comment: @Yves: You'll need to change the `tolstyle` and `modifier` styles: Try `\tikzset{
    tolstyle/.style={
        draw,
        on chain=going right,
        inner ysep=0pt,
        minimum height=1.7em,
        font=\sffamily
    },
    type/.style={tol#1},
    modifier/.style={tolmodifier,font={\sffamily #1}}
}`

Comment: This works on my trials, except for the numbers that remain typeset in the document font, and are not changed into sf fonts. I  have also commented out from the macro the line below, that is probably no longer necessary.... %\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

Comment: @Yves: Can you email me an example document where the font change doesn't work?

Comment: @Jake, I know this is quite an old topic, but did you manage to make a package out of this ?