# How to create Surface finish texture symbols with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing, engineering

Relate to [How to create geometry tolerance symbols with TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53471/how-to-create-geometry-tolerance-symbols-with-tikz)

I want flexibility, adaptive control by parameter, thanks for your answer.

```
20160627 update start:
For example 
\RF{a=Rz1.6,b=xx,c=xx,d=xx,e=xx,romoval=1}
\RF{a=Ra3.2,b=xx,c=mill,d=xx,e=xx,romoval=0}
Can display as the the picture. If the parameter is emplty ,it will be  undisplay
update end
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_finish

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,amsmath,tikz,type1cm,fix-cm}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newlength{\XHeight}
\newlength{\XWidth}

\newcommand*\RF[3]{\ensuremath{
      \settowidth{\XWidth}{#1}
      \addtolength{\XWidth}{.4em}
      \setlength{\XHeight}{\XWidth}
      \tikz[baseline]{
        \draw 
        (.75\XWidth,.3\XHeight) -- 
        (0.25\XWidth,.3\XHeight) -- 
        (.495\XWidth,-0.1\XHeight) -- 
        (.98\XWidth,.7\XHeight) --
        (1.5\XWidth,.7\XHeight) ;
        \node at (0.5\XWidth,.5\XHeight)[scale=0.66] {$#1$};
        \node at (1.25\XWidth,.9\XHeight)[scale=0.66] {$#2$};        
        \node at (1.25\XWidth,.5\XHeight)[scale=0.66] {$#3$};           
      }
    }
}

\begin{document}
test \RF{3.2}{Mill}{Rz}test \RF{0.8} {grinder}{}test\\\RF{0.8} {}{}test\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want, but I would make the following changes on general principles.

BTW, do you really want to use $...$ instead of \textit{...}?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand*\RF[3]% #1=(not in diagram), #2=a, #3=c
{\bgroup% use local registers 0-2
  \dimendef\XWidth=0
  \dimendef\XHeight=1
  \dimendef\XTop=2
  \setlength{\XTop}{1em}% minimum
  \settowidth{\XWidth}{$#2$}%
  \ifdim\XWidth>\XTop \XTop=\XWidth \fi
  \settowidth{\XWidth}{$#3$}%
  \ifdim\XWidth>\XTop \XTop=\XWidth \fi
  \setlength{\XTop}{0.66\XTop}% scale=0.66
  \settowidth{\XWidth}{$#1$}%
  \addtolength{\XWidth}{.4em}%
  \setlength{\XHeight}{\XWidth}%
  \tikz[baseline]{
        \draw 
        (.75\XWidth,.3\XHeight) -- 
        (0.25\XWidth,.3\XHeight) -- 
        (.495\XWidth,-0.1\XHeight) -- 
        (.98\XWidth,.7\XHeight) --
        +(\XTop,0) ;% use relative doordinate
        \node at (0.5\XWidth,.5\XHeight)[scale=0.66] {$#1$};
        \node at (\XWidth+0.5\XTop,.9\XHeight)[scale=0.66] {$#2$};        
        \node at (\XWidth+0.5\XTop,.5\XHeight)[scale=0.66] {$#3$};           
      }%
\egroup}


\begin{document}
test \RF{3.2}{Mill}{Rz}test \RF{0.8} {grinder}{}test\\\RF{0.8}{}{}test\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks,the code in the question that was learned from others is too hard. I am finding the best ,beautiful solution always.