# Metrology tolerance and fits

Tags: math-mode

How can i type meteorological tolerance, limits and fits etc, like double superscripts one on another notations using latex can any one please help me in this regard?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  We don't sign our questions with our name, since it appears in your logo already.

Comment: You could help us, and tell with more details what do you want. Moreover, if you tried anything, the code (even with errors) would be welcome.

Comment: Just updated a typo in the title (I think) - firs => fits. If that was wrong, sorry. You may also care to reconsider *meteorological* (=> metrological) in the body.

Comment: Use UTF-8 or maths `\plusminus` (.0x): ±0.01

Comment: @Brent.Longborough metrology as in an engineering metrology lab, nothing to do with metereology:)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides My point exactly!

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15705/how-to-typeset-dimensional-tolerances-mechanical-engineering-with-latex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you mean something like this, which I have embodied in the macro

`\dscript{upper}{lower}`.

Here is my MWE, which uses the layout described at http://www.slideshare.net/Nuumero1/metrology-vtu-unit2-limits-fits-and-tolerances:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\dscript[2]{\bgroup\stackon{\scriptstyle#2}{\scriptstyle#1}\egroup}
\setstackgap{S}{1pt}
\begin{document}
$\phi 40^\dscript{+0.05}{-0.05}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

As egreg suggests, and if legibility is not an issue, you may substitute (2 times) `\scriptscriptstyle` for `\scriptstyle` in my `\dscript` definition, in order to obtain the result:

[image]

There are other customs for the layout, such as that found at https://books.google.com/books?id=9rNldaV3FwcC&pg=PT372&lpg=PT372&dq=metrology+fits+tolerances&source=bl&ots=E3Bu3oPDQt&sig=RTJmKolkYmg3lEPc6JbfjFJiaI8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Ox6tVPy4NourggS23oCgBw&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=metrology%20fits%20tolerances&f=false , which can be obtained with

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\dscript[2]{\bgroup#1\egroup_\bgroup#2\egroup}
\begin{document}
$\phi 40^\dscript{+0.05}{-0.05}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\scriptscriptsize` would be better, in my opinion.

Comment: Even with the `\scriptscriptsize`, this implementation seriously disturbs interline spacing. I am not sure if there is a better way.

Comment: @PaulGessler These notations tend to be on schematic diagrams, rather than as part of inline text