# How to typeset asymmetrical confidence level limits / uncertainties?

Tags: amsmath, stackengine

Below is an example of an asymmetrical limit (or uncertainty)

[image]

How can I typeset this in a \LaTeX equation? Such pair of numbers should be vertically stacked while being vertically center-aligned with rest of the equation.

Solution

$X^{+Y}_{-Z}$

Comment: @reportaman In such cases, one cannot write `x=1 +0.1 -0.09 cm` because this would look like an arithmetic expression, not an experimental measurement. The reader would think that this is equivalent to `x=1.01 cm`, and confusion would arise. In such cases, we have to present the uncertainty (the "plus and minus" `\pm` part) "stacked" so that the positive limit is stacked on top of the negative limit.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200301/metrology-tolerance-and-fits

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to stack asymmetrical limits using macro `\Vectorstack` from package [stackengine](https://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine?lang=en)  (based on further clarification you provide in comments to your question):

Output:
[image: Screenshot of output]

Code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\[
  %\setstackgap{L}{\baselineskip} % Uncomment and change this if you want to adjust vertical spacing between stacked content
  A = B 
  \enskip \Vectorstack{+0.60 -0.59}
  \enskip \textrm{cm}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose this solution using `nccmath` with the `\mrel`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{nccmath}
\begin{document} $L=+0.39\!\mrel{+0.60\\[.12ex]-0.59} \mathrm{cm}$
\end{document}
```

---

Increasing the value of `[...ex]`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{nccmath}
\begin{document} $L=+0.39\!\mrel{+0.60\\[2ex]-0.59} \mathrm{cm}$
\end{document}
```

[image]