# How to typeset asymmetrical confidence level limits / uncertainties with amsmath?

Tags: amsmath

Below is an example of an asymmetrical limit (or uncertainty)

[image: asymmetrical limit]

How can I typeset this in a \LaTeX equation? Such pair of numbers should be vertically stacked while being vertically center-aligned with rest of the equation.

Comment: This question is forked from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/566363/192717

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to typeset asymmetrical confidence level limits / uncertainties?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566278/how-to-typeset-asymmetrical-confidence-level-limits-uncertainties)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is somewhat trivial

```
z=1.0^{+0.5}_{-0.3}
```

Comment: This question is forked from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/566363/192717